# MySQL INSERT and UPDATE with IF condition

Tags: mysql, database, insert-update, on-duplicate-key

I have a simple MySQL Database like:

```
CREATE TABLE `tab_update` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `description` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and some data inside:

```
INSERT INTO `tab_update` (`id`, `number`, `description`) VALUES ('111', '5', 'first value');
INSERT INTO `tab_update` (`id`, `number`, `description`) VALUES ('222', '5', 'first value');
INSERT INTO `tab_update` (`id`, `number`, `description`) VALUES ('333', '5', 'first value');
```

What I want is to:

- insert data to the database, if the same 'id' does not exist already

or

- update data if both below conditions are met:

  a) 'id' is already in the database

  b) new number value is bigger than the number stored already

What I am trying to do now is:

```
INSERT INTO tab_update (id, number, description) VALUES (333, 1, 'second value') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number = GREATEST(number, VALUES(number)), description = 'second value'
```

this works partially - inserts data or update, however, I have a wrong behavior. If we have 'number = 1' (which is less then 5) this should not update the record.
At the moment keeps updating description, but should not.

Could you please guys help me improve this query?

update:
I am trying also:

```
INSERT INTO tab_update (id, number, description) VALUES (333, 6, 'second value') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
number = GREATEST(number, VALUES(number)), 
description = IF(VALUES(number) > number, VALUES(description), description)
```

but last line does not work as expected.

Comment: You cannot do this using insert, consider using a stored procedure, your front end if you have one or a trigger to throw away the insert for the last scenario

Comment: @p.salmon is there no option to use something like "if" or "case"?